# How to create plugin for wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I have the code of a html plugin that I bought and thought it will work for wordpess(didnt know it is only for wordpress)
Could anybody please help be changing it into a plugin for wordpress?

Comment: `thought it will work for wordpess, didnt know it is only for wordpress` Is it for Wordpress or not?? Whether or not, this question appears to be off topic here.

Comment: My apology. It is all html, java and css for an html site. not wordpress

Comment: Include js and css in header, add html to your template wherever you want to add it.

Comment: Okay, should js and css files should be stored in the theme's directory?

Comment: Yes. Refer to Wordpress documentation to learn how to enqueue scripts "the right way". But if you just want to get going, simply do as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer this [Wordpress article](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) to learn about plugin writing. However, you might just need to alter your theme's template to add the HTML plugin you have.